# How to play and pause video in vue-video-player when mouse enter/leave?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video.js

I want to play videos using [vue-video-player](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-video-player) in vuejs which is wrapper on `video.js`.

So I have an array of videos and I want to play the video when the mouse is hover the video and when the mouse is leave then pause the video.

also I hide the controls (I don't want to see the button or progress bar) using `control:false`.

I try to do with `@mouseenter` or `@mouseleave` events but they not works.

Any idea what I can do?

Here my code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-mooo4)